# How to pass data between distincts components?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to pass a simple value from `component A` to `component B` but I can't use props because it's not using **parent / child component communication**.

Here an example to be more precise of my **component A** :

```
_redirect = () => {
   // redirect to Component B
} 

<button onClick={() => this._redirect()} >
   <img src='http://source.com' alt='my_image' />
</button>
```

And I would like to get the `alt` value to my component B.

How can I do that please ?

Comment: If you are simply passing data from one to the other then loft the state to closest common ancestor. If simply trying to pass some data with a redirect then you can pass state on route transitions. Perhaps if you update your question to provide more code and a clearer picture of the app structure, how components A and B are relative to one another, we can provide an answer.

Comment: redux store might be a good way to do this.

Comment: Thanks @Han you right I checked it on https://redux.js.org/api/store and now I can do it, thank you so much. You can add an answer if you want so I can put this ticket as resolved if your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it by using redux store. [Redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/api/store)